# When should I use new and smart pointer

Tags: c++

I read the following code

```
student* input(string name, int age)
{
  student *st = new student(name,age);
  return st;
}
```

where `student` is just a simple class with following function and member

```
class student{

  public:
    student(string na, int ag);
    void show();
  private:
    string name;
    int age;
};
```

`show` is just a function to print a sentence. Main function is the following

```
int main(){
  student *st = input("guagua",25);
  if(!st){ cout<<"no pointer"<<endl;}
  st->show();
  delete st;
  return 0;
}
```

My understanding is that because I use `new` so in the main function I need delete `st`. If I use the following code the take the place of `student *st = new student(name,age);`, do I still need to delete `st`?

```
  student te(name,age);
  student *st;
  st = &te;
```

If not because now st is a raw pointer, why people need `new`? We can all use the similar way to take the place of `new`.
Another problem is that some people suggest to use smart pointer to avoid we forget delete a pointer. Then I just use raw pointer in every place like above, it seems we do not need `delete` at all? I know there must some place I didn't understand, hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a smart pointer and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one)

Comment: The general rule of thumb is that you need a `delete` for every `new`. If you don't use `new` then you don't need `delete`. (Note that your second example is not a smart pointer. See the above link for more details about what a smart pointer is.)

Comment: Modern `c++` encourages you to not use `new`.

Answer (score 3):

> My understanding is that because I use new so in the main function I need delete `st`.

That is correct.

> If I use the following code the take the place of student *st = new student(name,age);, do I still need to delete st?
>
> ```
> student te(name,age);
> student *st;
> st = &te;
> ```

No. You will probably crash. Remember that stack values are destroyed after their scope. In this code, `te` will die after the function returns. `st` will point to a dead object.

> Another problem is that some people suggest to use smart pointer to avoid we forget delete a pointer.

Indeed, you should not have `new` or `delete` unless you're doing something special. You can get away easily with smart pointer without any runtime penalty. You're example using `std::unique_ptr` (a unique owner, many observers) will look like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<student> input(string name, int age) {
    // auto is std::unique_ptr<student>
    auto st = std::make_unique<student>(name,age);
    return st;
}

int main() {
    // auto is std::unique_ptr<student>
    auto st = input("guagua",25);

    if(!st){
        std::cout << "no pointer" << std::endl;
    }
    
    st->show();
    // delete st; // no delete to do
    return 0;
}
```

Even better, if you can do it with values, you won't need dynamic memory management or unique pointers at all:

```
student input(string name, int age) {
    student st{name, age};
    return st;
}

int main() {
    // auto is student
    auto st = input("guagua",25);

    // The following is not needed, a value is never null
    //if(!st){
    //    std::cout << "no pointer" << std::endl;
    //}
    
    st.show();

    // delete st; // no delete to do
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a small nitpick: The local variable in `input()` isn’t needed at all. It could be a simple *return* one-liner. But still: +1

Comment: @besc yes, but I wanted to be the closest to his code as possible